# How to use Autodesk Forge Extensions with React.js?

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I want to add my Forge extensions to React. I use [Forge RCDB](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/components) repository for example, but i can't understand the structure of this project. I want to know is it possible to use it on existing project and which files are important to use?
Also i want to know, is it possible to use it with function components, instead of class components?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you manage with using forge extensions?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the samples on https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io are more for demo purposes, not to provide reusable pieces of code.

Consider looking at https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io instead - it's also a collection of demos but each feature is packaged into a self-contained, reusable Forge Viewer extensions. Feel free to submit a PR to https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions if you'd like to see other extensions there as well.